# Digest Already In Progress when child component is destroyed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend

I am having a weird issue in an AngularJS application. The error is the classic `$digest already in process` error. I have googled and looked at similar questions, but none of the proposed solutions worked.
The error is occuring in a child component. The child component is basically just a wrapper around a regular text input with some styling. The child component's `ng-model` is bound ot the `item` being passed as input. The child component ouptus events when the input is being `focused` and `blurred`.
The component hierarchy is as follows: A parent component that is a modal, the child component is a text input. The parent component (modal) can be closed via the ESC Key. The error appears if I open the modal, select the input (don't type anything in it) and then close it via the ESC Key.

Here is the child component template

```
<div class="input-group has-feedback"'
     ng-class="{'has-error' : vm.item.errors.length > 0 ,
                'has-success' : vm.item.isFulfilled}">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="fa fa-asterisk"></i>
        </div>
            <input
            ng-model="vm.item.pendingBarcode"
            type="text"/>
</div>
```

Here is the child component JS

```
.component('rfidInput', {
        templateUrl: 
'swipeables/templates/swipeables.rfidReader.tpl.html',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindings: {
            item: '<',
            id: '<',
            onFocus: '&',
            onBlur: '&',
            focus: '<'
        },
        controller: function() {

            this.onInputFocus = function() {
                if(typeof this.onFocus === 'function') {
                    this.onFocus({index:this.id})
                }
            }

            this.onInputBlur = function() {
                if(typeof this.onBlur === 'function') {
                    this.onBlur({item:this.item});
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

I modified the child component's template down to only `ng-model` in reality there are also `ng-blur` and `ng-focus` bindings, but I removed those to drill down the source.

Here is how the parent template uses the child template

```
<rfid-input on-blur="fulfill(item)" focus="currentFocusedScanIndex"
            on-focus="onScanFocus(index)" item="item" id="$index">
</rfid-input>
```

Now what is extremely interesting is that the error only happens if I click into the input and then close the modal. The error does not happen if I open the modal and close it again without selecting the input...

I am at a loss and don't know how to make it work. I tried the `$timeout` solutions as well to fire the `onFocus` and `onBlur` after a $timeout to not interfere with the current $digest cycle.

Any help, or suggestions in how to solve this would be greatly appreciated. If there is also some suggestions on how to change that child component that would be great too.

Comment: See [AngularJS Error Reference - inprog - Diagnosing This Error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog#diagnosing-this-error).

Comment: I don't know why you are checking that the expression bindings are functions. In the case of expression (`&`) bindings, the $compile service always binds a `scope.$eval` function that executes the expression on the attribute even if the attribute doesn't exist.

Comment: @georgeawg thanks for the tip. I did not know that. Anyways, I am closer to the cause of the issue. The parent component is hosted in an angular-ui-bootstrap $uibModal instance which provides the ESC click to close functionality. I found that the error is thrown when I modify the $scope in the `catch` that gets triggered when i click ESC to close the modal. In the catch i often do a refresh of data by calling our API. Now I was able to fix the error by wrapping that refresh in a $timeout... like `catch(()=> $timeout(()=> refresh()));` Looks ugly, but I assume that was what was interfering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Docs:

> ### Diagnosing This Error
>
> When you get this error it can be rather daunting to diagnose the cause of the issue. The best course of action is to investigate the stack trace from the error. You need to look for places where `$apply` or `$digest` have been called and find the context in which this occurred.
>
> There should be two calls:
>
> The first call is the good $apply/$digest and would normally be triggered by some event near the top of the call stack.
>
> The second call is the bad `$apply`/`$digest` and this is the one to investigate.
>
> Once you have identified this call you work your way up the stack to see what the problem is.
>
> If the second call was made in your application code then you should look at why this code has been called from within an `$apply`/`$digest`. It may be a simple oversight or maybe it fits with the sync/async scenario described earlier.
>
> If the second call was made inside an AngularJS directive then it is likely that it matches the second programmatic event trigger scenario described earlier. In this case you may need to look further up the tree to what triggered the event in the first place

For more information, see [AngularJS Error Reference - inprog - Diagnosing This Error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog#diagnosing-this-error).